# append Dictionary<String, Any> to class array SWIFT 3

Tags: arrays, json, swift, alamofire

Could you please advise. if there any way to append Dictionary to class which was declared as Array? like var cellData = [CellData[() Basically, I'm parsing data from JSON and there is a for in loop which I'm trying pass in this class and then put this data in MainVC in viewDidLoad() in order to update my cell. I'm about to learn Swift, so I'm not sure if I'm all doing right and how to fix the problem.

When I try to append, the error says 'Cannot conver value of type 'Dictionary,String, Any>' to expected argument type 'CellData'

```
func downloadBlogDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {

    Alamofire.request(CURRENT_URL).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result

        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {

            if let items = dict["items"] as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {

                for obj in items {

                    if let title = items[0]["title"] as? String {
                       self._authorName = title
                        print(self._authorName)
                    }

                    if let published = items[0]["published"] as? String {
                        self._publishedDate = published
                        print(self._publishedDate)
                    }

                    if let author = items[0]["author"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                        if let name = author["displayName"] as? String {
                            self._authorName = name
                            print(self._authorName)
                        }
                    }

                    // add element obj to class array
                    self.cellData.append(obj)
                }

            }
        }

        completed()
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you using https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: Please copy and paste the code and the error message into the question instead of providing an image. You can select the code and click the `{}` button to automatically format it for the question.

Comment: @Keiwan thank you. Just did it.

Comment: You need to create `CellData` objects from the dictionaries (`obj`). By the way `obj` in the loop is the same as `items[x]` - @JuicyFruit SwiftyJSON does not solve the problem

Comment: @vadian it won't , but it would much easier to understand and make what @Sargot tries to, without `as!`

Comment: @JuicyFruit No, it's not related to the kind of parsing at all. The issue is a type mismatch.

Comment: @vadian I do understand, but I doubt some one here would write whole code, that needed, and to explain it all in theory is quite a task. If he've managed to get into Alamofire, I am 100% sure he would understand his mistake while trying SwiftyJSON.

Comment: @vadian and JuicyFruit thank you for your replies.  I'm okay with Alomafire and I'm sure SwiftyJSON will not solve the problem. As JuicyFruit said, its all about mismatch in type. I was able to parse data and put in my cell if I use this function in mainVC and use constructor in cellData class, however I want to use MVC pattern and separate code but faced with this problem. I'll try to use advice that JuicyFruit gave above and see what'll happen. Sorry for my bad English)